# WPF. Применение стиля к image

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть стиль для изменения размера компонента в разметке Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type self:ResizablePanel}" TargetType="{x:Type self:ResizablePanel}">
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type self:ResizablePanel}">
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeNWSE" Background="Gray" Width="3" Height="3"
                                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ThumbDirection="TopLeft"/>

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeWE" Background="LightGray" Width="1" 
                                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ThumbDirection="Left"/>

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeNESW" Background="Gray" Width="3" Height="3" 
                                          Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ThumbDirection="BottomLeft" />

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeNS" Background="LightGray" Height="1" 
                                          Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ThumbDirection="Bottom" />

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeNWSE" Background="Gray" Width="3" Height="3" 
                                          Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" ThumbDirection="BottomRight" />

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeWE" Background="LightGray" Width="1"  
                                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ThumbDirection="Right"/>

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeNESW" Background="Gray" Width="3" Height="3" 
                                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ThumbDirection="TopRight"/>

                        <self:Resizer Cursor="SizeNS" Background="LightGray"  Height="1" 
                                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ThumbDirection="Top"/>

                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                         Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"></ContentPresenter>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Вот его применение к RichTextBox в разметке Xaml:

```
<self:ResizablePanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="300" Width="Auto" MinHeight="60" Margin="20, 30, 20, 20">
      <RichTextBox x:Name="SomeName"
      </RichTextBox>
</self:ResizablePanel>
```

`Resizable Panel` определен в отдельном классе

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TextEditorForDimploma
{
   public class ResizablePanel : ContentControl
   {
      static ResizablePanel()
      {
        // This will allow us to create a Style in Generic.xaml with target           type ResizablePanel.
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ResizablePanel), new    FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ResizablePanel)));
      }
   }
}
```

Необходимо применить стиль к компоненту Image в коде.

При использовании `<... x:Key = "SomeKey">` и попытке найти его в коде 
 
`style = (Style)FindResource("SomeKey") as Style;` не выводит image совсем.

`style = (Style)FindResource("SomeKey") as Style;` используется в обработчике события, отвечающего за добавление рисунка.

Comment: А как определён сам `ResizablePanel`?

Comment: Не может быть такого «не выводит Image». Может быть «выводит нулевого размера», «выводит с Opacity=0», «бросает исключение». Опишите свою ошибку в точности. И ещё, а где находится ваш этот код `style = (Style)FindResource("SomeKey") as Style`? Вангую, что в конструкторе.

Comment: А всё же, покажите точный код. Вы, надеюсь, знаете, что если объект не добавлен в визуальное дерево, то `FindResource` до окна не дойдёт, некак ему.